mudblazor expand and and selected values not working
Hello I'm kinda new at mudblazor and I don't know how to manage with expand and show selected values. It shows the feature that I've waited and I can see the child features because expand button created but when I click expand button nothing happens. also when I click a feature I can't see it on selected values part.
@page "/featurepage"
@using ProtaTestTrack2.Helpers
@using ProtaTestTrack2.Services
@using MudBlazor

<MudTreeView Items="TreeItems" MultiSelection="false" SelectedValueChanged="FeatureChanged" @bind-ActivatedValue="ActivatedValue" @bind-SelectedValues="SelectedValues" Dense>
    <ItemTemplate Context="item">
        <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@item.IsExpanded" Items="@item.TreeItems" Value="@item"
                        Icon="@item.Icon" Text="@item.Title" EndText="@item.Number?.ToString()" EndTextTypo="@Typo.caption">
            <BodyContent>
                <MudText Style="justify-self: start;">
                    <MudHighlighter Text="@context.Text" />
                </MudText>
            </BodyContent>
        </MudTreeViewItem>
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudTreeView>

<MudText Style="width: 100%" Typo="@Typo.subtitle2">Selected Feature: @_ActivatedValue?.Title</MudText>

@code {

private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar; }
    set { myVar = value; }
}


[Inject]
FeatureService featureService { get; set; }

private TreeItemData _ActivatedValue;
[Parameter]
public TreeItemData ActivatedValue { get
    {
        return _ActivatedValue;
    } set
    {
        _ActivatedValue = value;
        FeatureChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<TreeItemData> FeatureChanged { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public HashSet<TreeItemData> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();

private HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var pop = await PopulateTree();
}

public async Task<bool> PopulateTree()
{
    //<https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/7899>

    // todo cache this features
    var features = await featureService.GetAllFeaturesAsync();
    var treehelper = new Helpers.TreeviewHelper(features);
    treehelper.BuildTree();
    TreeItems = treehelper.TreeItems;

    StateHasChanged();
    return true;
}
}

I tried to add render mode at app.razor but didn't work as well.
